# How to check if elements are linked up/down in MS access?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-access

I have a MS access file (office 2007) with a lot of "history".

So I have many tables and querys.

I would like to clean it but I would not know how to check which elements can be deleted without affecting the use of others (tabs, queries, forms, reports)

Comment: What have you tried? How about the built in tools like Object Dependencies or the Database Documenter?

Comment: @CharlieRB this is what I ask for: I did not know was so easy. If you reply with it I can accept your reply otherwise I can delete the question that seems trivial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use built in tools, like `Object Dependencies` and `Database Documenter` to do what you are seeking.

For example:

> The Database Documenter is a handy tool when you’re in the process of
> building your database and at the end because it lists everything
> related to your database in one report.

[image]

[Source](http://www.keystonelearning.com/resources/articles/access_2007_database_documenter)